# C#, send outlook vCalendar meeting request with auto accept/decline from a specific email address

Tags: outlook

In C#, is there a way to send a "vCalendar/ics" meeting request that can be accepted/declined automatically in user's outlook calendar? Here, the auto acceptance or decline to happen for a specific sender's email address. I have tried PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED/DECLINED, Nothing works.